# W3 Total Cache: minified CSS and JS files not found in AWS S3-based CDN

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, w3-total-cache

My configuration consists of a Wordpress installation with the **W3 Total Cache** plugin that is set up to cache resources on a CDN (Amazon S3+Cloudfront).

The HTML resources and images are loaded correctly, but the problem is with **minified** CSS and JS, as they were renamed by the plugin (e.g. `style.css` renamed to `18704.css`).

The problem might be in how I write the URI in the site's HTML code, where the original `style.css` is referred to, instead of the generated filename:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wptheme-style-css'  href='https://<distribution_id>.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/wptheme/style.css.gzip?ver=1.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Cloudfront configuration:

- Two origins added `example-com.s3.amazonaws.com` and `example.com`

S3 configuration:

- Bucket policy:

.

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
    }
 ]
}
```

- The files stored inside S3 bucket have the correct MIME type, although some may be missing CORS policy:

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Browser console:

```
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):96 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):96
(anonymous) @ (index):96
www.example.com/:199 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):199
(anonymous) @ (index):199
www.example.com/:1353 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):1353
(anonymous) @ (index):1353
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
twitter-widgets.js.gzip Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wp-signup.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Chrome's network console:

[image: Network console]

The actual minified and compressed CSS and JS files in the S3 bucket:

[image: S3 Bucket]

Comment: Did you find a solution?